# how to pass a pure sql query to laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, orm

This SQL:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_see_all_video
from users u
WHERE 7 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lecciones_users lu WHERE lu.uuid = u.uuid)
```

I tried this code but did not work:

```
$data = LeccionesUsers::select(
    DB::raw('COUNT(*) AS total_ase_vis_videos'),
    DB::raw('where 7 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lecciones_users where leccion_users.uuid = users.uuid)')
)
    ->join('users', 'lecciones_users.uuid', '=', 'users.uuid')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are not correctly forming your query. You can do `->toSql();` instead of `->get();` and you would see the final SQL (would definitely not be the same as the one you wrote first).

So, you should have this to have the same SQL:

```php
$total_see_all_video = LeccionesUsers::whereRaw('7 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lecciones_users where leccion_users.uuid = users.uuid)')
    ->count();
```

---

Please, try my query (and also run `->toSql()` to see if you have a correct SQL).

I would still recommend to use relationships and it is very weird to do `7 = query`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
DB::query()->fromSub('Raw sql query here..')
```

and then can perform actions on this.For the reference you can use the documentation [fromSub](https://laravel.com/api/8.x//Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_fromSub)

You can also look into this convert this where break this query to parts to be used accordingly. You can use this section for the reference purpose:
[Laravel-Raw-Expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#raw-expressions)

Hope this will help you with the result.